# Sci-fi book I read in the late 90s and was found in the childrens/ young adult area

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

It was about a girl who found a spaceship and befriended the young male alien. I can’t remember if there was a parental unit for the alien but I think there was. I want to say the spaceship was egg shaped but this was more than 20 years ago.

Comment: Was the alien humanoid? Could they pass for human? Did the ship land or crash? Any special abilities? Was it just friendship? Romance? Did they have any disagreements that led to the friendship ending or going on pause?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.